# ASIHTTPRequest Error messages - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHttpRequest. I need to know what this error message means ? and how could i resolve it

> Request error <ASIHTTPRequest: 0xbedc00> -- Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x270230 {NSUnderlyingError=0x250cf0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}

There are many more error messages; the above is `Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1` Other are `Code=2`, `Code=3` ... upto `Code=10`. I need to what these are too ?

**edit:** 
The errors gets displayed inside the `if condition`

```
 SBJsonParser *p = [SBJsonParser new];              
       NSDictionary *content = [pobjectWithString:[request responseString]];       
       if(!content){       
           NSLog(@" %@", p.errorTrace);
           return;
       }
```

Comment: Can you may post the code which raises this error?

Comment: I have added a code. I need to know what these error means. Furthermore, there are 10 similar error messages sent by ASIHTTPRequest. I need to know what they are and how to handle it. :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error means that the host cannot be contacted, most often because you don't have a network connection.

Here are the error codes defined in `ASIHTTPRequest.h`

```
typedef enum _ASINetworkErrorType {
    ASIConnectionFailureErrorType = 1,
    ASIRequestTimedOutErrorType = 2,
    ASIAuthenticationErrorType = 3,
    ASIRequestCancelledErrorType = 4,
    ASIUnableToCreateRequestErrorType = 5,
    ASIInternalErrorWhileBuildingRequestType  = 6,
    ASIInternalErrorWhileApplyingCredentialsType  = 7,
    ASIFileManagementError = 8,
    ASITooMuchRedirectionErrorType = 9,
    ASIUnhandledExceptionError = 10,
    ASICompressionError = 11

} ASINetworkErrorType;
```

Comment: I guess i cann't handle these errors, so what kind of error messages should i show the users when one of these errors occur.

Comment: Show `[error localizedDescription]`, that's generally what I do.

Comment: According to my code how could i print this. When i say content.localizedDescription i get an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

you should try something like this

```
-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{ 

       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[request.error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
       [alertView show];
}
```