# ASIHTTPRequest getting failed everytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, httprequest, asihttprequest

Iam using ASIHTTPRequest POST Method for getting json from server and till yesterday i was able to get json from  server but since yesterday evening am not getting anything from serverI tried to run the code in simulator then am getting json from server (My internet is little slow now). I confirmed that there is no changes in server.

This is the  error getting in my log

```
Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x170268400 {NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred, NSUnderlyingError=0x17005e4b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)"}
```

This is my code to get JSON

```
- (void)fetchData
{
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"action", @"conferenceId", nil];

    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"query", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];

    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    NSString* jsonBody = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"jsonBody%@",jsonBody);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://exampleurl.com/query"];

    _queryRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [_queryRequest setPostValue:jsonBody forKey:@"queryJSON"];
    NSLog(@"_queryRequest%@", [_queryRequest valueForKey:@"postData"]);
    [_queryRequest setDelegate:self];
    [_queryRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [_queryRequest startAsynchronous];
       NSLog(@"startAsynchronous");
}


#pragma mark HTTPRequest Delegate Methods

- (void)requestStarted
{
    NSLog(@"requestStarted");
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    responseString = [responseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);
    if (request == _queryRequest)
    {
        [self processQueryResponse:responseString];
    }
}
- (void) requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"%@",request.error);
}
```

Following is the value of _queryRequest variable

```
(
        {
        key = queryJSON;
        value = "{\"action\":\"query\",\"conferenceId\":1}";
    }
)
```

Please help me, why it suddenly getting failed in devices???

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASIHTTPRequest Error messages - Beginner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454609/asihttprequest-error-messages-beginner)

Comment: Move to afnetworking ,still developing using asihttp? its like using t34 in modern day battle.Asihttp was a networking legend of its time, but no more how did you move it to arc?